# Only controls and audio load and work on video in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm building a website with php that echos the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video id="video_media" style="position:relative; z-index:1; display:block; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:700px;" controls>
      <source src="uploads/15 dialogo 13.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I view the page in google chrome there is only a set of controls. The audio plays if I press play, but the video does not show in google chrome. In safari and microsoft edge the video will show up and play fine with the controls.

I didn't tag php in this because when I make an html file with this code the same thing happens, so I'm fairly sure its not an issue with the php.

I've googled this a lot in the last couple days and I haven't been able to find anything about other people having the same problem. I've changed settings on chrome on my computer to try to view the video but that hasn't done anything. I also don't think that it's a chrome settings issue since I've never noticed other sites' videos not playing on my browser.

If there's an obvious answer that I'm missing, sorry... I'm fairly new to web design and I've never used videos on a web page before. If there is another question that has been asked that has the same answer, also, sorry. I did search here first, but I might have missed it. Please just point me to that page. Thanks,

------------UPDATE------------

It doesn't work on firefox either by the way.

Also, I can download the file with audio and video working after download. It's just not playing in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with:

```
<source src="./uploads/15 dialogo 13.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
```

or meaby changing the name of the video:

```
<source src="./uploads/test.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
```

--UPDATE--

Apparently the problem is generated by video codecs

Comment: Tried both suggestions. Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Did you try in firefox? meaby a problem with the cache of chrome?

Comment: Ok. so let's try the next, disable hardware-accelerated video decode. Check the next [link](https://forums.adobe.com/message/10183762#10183762)

Comment: This doesn't fix it either, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you try with another video? meaby its a problem with the codecs

Comment: It appears that was the problem. The new mp4 plays. I get the videos I post from contracted employees. Do you happen to know what do I need to ask for from my employees in order to ensure that the video will play? In terms of video specifications?

Comment: Meaby ask for an video with an specific codecs (like the video that plays). You can know the video codecs with this: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download

Answer (score 0):

I have one mp4 video that won't play in Chrome or Firefox. The audio plays, with the controls, but no video. What fixed it was pulling the video into Final Cut Pro, which said that it was a non-standard size or format, then I "shared" (exported) the file back onto my hard drive. The new file plays in all the browsers. The file size jumped from 32 MB to 98 MB, for a three-minute SD video.